# Spring @Transactional annotation not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Currently I'm making a Spring course on Udemy and I'm having problems with the `@Transactional` annotation in the `CustomerDAO` class. I'm using Maven and Java 8. It simply doesn't works, here is the response from Tomcat 9:

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

Type Exception Report

Message Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1013)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

Root Cause

javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.checkTransactionNeeded(SessionImpl.java:3552)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1444)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1440)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.flush(SessionFactoryUtils.java:147)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionSynchronization.beforeCommit(SpringSessionSynchronization.java:95)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerBeforeCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:96)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerBeforeCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:922)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:714)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:533)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:304)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    net.matbm.springlearn.dao.CustomerDAO$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6447db19.getCustomers(<generated>)
    net.matbm.springlearn.dao.CustomerDAO$HOTSWAPAGENT_$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$466694ed.invoke(<generated>)
    org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    HotswapSpringCallback_1796692748.intercept(HotswapSpringCallback_1796692748.java)
    net.matbm.springlearn.dao.CustomerDAO$HOTSWAPAGENT_$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$feb7e678.getCustomers(<generated>)
    net.matbm.springlearn.service.CustomerService.getAllCustomers(CustomerService.java:16)
    net.matbm.springlearn.controller.CustomerController.listCustomers(CustomerController.java:26)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

I've already seen another stack overflow posts and none of them helped me solve the issue! Currently this is the second consecutive day I'm struggling with this issue. It simply doesn't works. I already tried to create a `servlet-context.xml` to "separate the contexts" but it doesn't solved the issue. Here is the source code related to the project:

`web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

    <display-name>spring-mvc-demo</display-name>

    <!-- Spring MVC Configs -->

    <!-- Step 1: Configure Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Step 2: Set up URL mapping for Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

`spring.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <!-- Add support for component scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="net.matbm.springlearn.config"/>

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
</beans>
```

`net.matbm.springlearn.config.AppConfig.java`

```
package net.matbm.springlearn.config;

import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource;
import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.PooledDataSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("net.matbm.springlearn")
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public PooledDataSource dataSource() throws PropertyVetoException {
        ComboPooledDataSource source = new ComboPooledDataSource();

        source.setDriverClass("org.postgresql.Driver");
        source.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/java");

        source.setUser("java");
        source.setPassword("java");

        source.setMinPoolSize(5);
        source.setMinPoolSize(20);
        source.setMinPoolSize(3000);

        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() throws PropertyVetoException {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("net.matbm.springlearn.model");

        factoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws PropertyVetoException {
        HibernateTransactionManager manager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        manager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());

        return manager;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("resources/");
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();

        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");

        return hibernateProperties;

    }
}
```

`net.matbm.controller.CustomerController.java`

```
package net.matbm.springlearn.controller;

import net.matbm.springlearn.service.CustomerService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerController {
    private final CustomerService customerService;

    @Autowired
    public CustomerController(CustomerService customerService) {
        this.customerService = customerService;
    }

    @RequestMapping()
    public String home() {
        return "customer/home";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/list")
    public String listCustomers(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("customers", customerService.getAllCustomers());

        return "customer/list-customers";
    }
}
```

`net.matbm.service.CustomerService.java`

```
package net.matbm.springlearn.service;

import net.matbm.springlearn.dao.CustomerDAO;
import net.matbm.springlearn.model.Customer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class CustomerService {
    @Autowired
    private CustomerDAO customerDAO;

    public List<Customer> getAllCustomers() {
        return customerDAO.getCustomers();
    }
}
```

`net.matbm.dao.CustomerDAO.java`

```
package net.matbm.springlearn.dao;

import net.matbm.springlearn.model.Customer;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public class CustomerDAO {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Transactional
    public List<Customer> getCustomers() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        Query<Customer> query =
                session.createQuery("from Customer", Customer.class);

        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

`net.matbm.model.Customer.java`

```
package net.matbm.springlearn.model;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    public Customer() {
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Customer{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

`pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>net.matbm</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringLearn</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>Spring Learn</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>5.1.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.validator/hibernate-validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.13.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-c3p0 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>SpringMaven</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                    <server>TomcatServer</server>
                    <path>/</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have no idea about your problem just use `@Transactional` in service layer.

Comment: I tried that too (I looked at the documentation and I should use at the service layer). But it doesn't solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing the `CustomerDAO` the transaction started working:

```
@Repository
public class CustomerDAOImpl implements CustomerDAO {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public List<Customer> getCustomers() {
        Query<Customer> query =
                (Query<Customer>) entityManager.createQuery("from Customer", Customer.class);

        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

Using `@PersistenceContext` instead of a `SessionFactory` resolved the issue. I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

in service layer you used the the @Autowired Annotation and DAO Layer you used the @Tranjaction annotation so thats why its giving an error.

so use the @Transactional Annotation in service layer and use the  @Autowired annotation in DAO Layer

Make change in Service layer shown below

```
 import net.matbm.springlearn.dao.CustomerDAO;
    import net.matbm.springlearn.model.Customer;
     import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

     import java.util.List;

    @Service
    public class CustomerService {
        @Autowired
        private CustomerDAO customerDAO;
     @Transactional
        public List<Customer> getAllCustomers() {
            return customerDAO.getCustomers();
        }
    }
```

Make change in DAO layer Shown below

```
package net.matbm.springlearn.dao;
import net.matbm.springlearn.model.Customer;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public class CustomerDAO {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

   @Override
    public List<Customer> getCustomers() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        Query<Customer> query =
                session.createQuery("from Customer", Customer.class);

        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've commented that out here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53581843/7308020

This was the issue too, the official documentation specifies that the `@Transactional` needs to be at the Services layer.

Answer (score 0):

As per exception looks like your transactionManager config is not correct.

Any specific reason for using `PlatformTransactionManager` ??

If not use this config

Working config for Transaction usinHibernatete 4 looks like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource({ "classpath:persistence-mysql.properties" })
@ComponentScan({ "org.baeldung.spring.persistence" })
public class PersistenceConfig {

   @Autowired
   private Environment env;

   @Bean
   public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
      LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
      sessionFactory.setDataSource(restDataSource());
      sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(
        new String[] { "org.baeldung.spring.persistence.model" });
      sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

      return sessionFactory;
   }

   @Bean
   public DataSource restDataSource() {
      BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
      dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
      dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
      dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
      dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.pass"));

      return dataSource;
   }

   @Bean
   @Autowired
   public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(
     SessionFactory sessionFactory) {

      HibernateTransactionManager txManager
       = new HibernateTransactionManager();
      txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

      return txManager;
   }

   @Bean
   public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
      return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
   }

   Properties hibernateProperties() {
      return new Properties() {
         {
            setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
              env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
            setProperty("hibernate.dialect",
              env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
            setProperty("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers",
             "true");
         }
      };
   }
}
```

More details [here](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-4-spring)

**Else** if you want a solution for `PlatformTransactionManager`

[This](https://www.baeldung.com/transaction-configuration-with-jpa-and-spring) might help

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast response. I used [this official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/EnableTransactionManagement.html) to setup the `PlatformTransactionManager`, that's why I'm using it. Making the changes you advised unfortunately didn't solved the issue. I've already looked at the second link you posted before creating this issue here.